# Call a function periodically using BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, backgroundworker

I have a C# windows form application. I want to update some labels by fetching information from the web. I want to call a function periodically using `BackgroundWorker`.

```
public partial class OptionDetails : Form
{
    static System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker worker = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
    static void fun()
    {
       worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
       worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
       worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
       worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
    static void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    { // some work }

    static void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    { // on completion }
}
```

If I use `Timer`, the UI hangs. How do I use `BackgroundWorker` to call `worker_DoWork` periodically?

My actual code:

```
public partial class myform: Form
{
    public myform()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public async Task Periodic(Action func, TimeSpan period, CancellationToken token)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            // throws an exception if someone has requested cancellation via the token.
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            func();

            // asynchronously wait 
            await Task.Delay(period);
        }
    }

    public async void hello()
    {
        await Periodic(getCurrentInfo, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), CancellationToken.None);
    }

    private void myform_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hello();
    }


    private void getCurrentInfo()
    {
        WebDataRetriever wdr = new WebDataRetriever();
        string name = "name";
        string url = String.Empty;
        string[] prices = new string[2];
        bool urlExists = url.TryGetValue(name, out url);
        if (urlExists)
        {
            wdr.processurl();  // time consuming function
            prices[0] = wdr.price1;
            prices[1] = wdr.price2;

            System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo nfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US", false).NumberFormat;
            if (prices != null)
            {
                // change labels
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I presume you used `System.Windows.Forms.timer`. Use `System.Threading.Timer` or `System.Timers.Timer`. It won't block the UI.

Comment: what version of .NET are you using? You can use async/await and `Task.Delay` if you are on .NET 4.5

Comment: @SriramSakthivel better to give also an advice on the UI Thread issues here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx

Comment: Apart from the System Timer you may also need the ReportProgress function to update the Labels in the UI thread: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - A WinForms Timer shouldn't block either.

Comment: I don't need to, @Steve did it. :)

Comment: @rako - Use a Timer to start the Bgw.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Depends upon what you do in the `Tick` handler. It will block if you have time consuming operations in it.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - Yea I forgot to mention. I am using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.

Comment: Then my first comment answers your question. If you need more specific answer you need to post more code.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Not really. `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` works on the UI thread so the UI hangs in case the task is time consuming. On the other hand, `System.Threading.Timer` does not run on the UI thread so the UI does not hang. But I can't use it because I need to change the label text which has to be done on the UI thread. Maybe I should  pass the text to the UI thread and then update the label text?

Comment: Then post your code instead of //Some work etc. Or at least post some code which mocks the original. I'll try to help. And which version of .net you're using?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution for what you need is probably to use a `Timer` to kick off `BackgroundWorker`, but using async/await I believe results in a more compact and elegant solution.

The solution below is an asynchronous method, for which the compiler generates a state machine. When the asynchronous method `Periodic` is invoked it starts executing up until the first `await` statement. In this case this is:

```
 await Task.Delay(period);
```

The expression awaited returns an awaitable, which is in this case a `Task`, but it can be [anything](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115642.aspx) that has a method `GetAwaiter` which returns a type implementing the `INotifyCompletion` interface or the `ICriticalNotifyCompletion` interface.

If this task is complete the method continues executing synchronously, if the task is not complete the method returns. Once the task is complete, execution of the method resumes after that `await` statement in the same `SynchronizationContext`. If you called this from a GUI thread, execution will resume in the GUI thread, but for your case it will resume on a `ThreadPool` thread because [console apps do not have a `SynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx).

`Task.Delay(period)` returns a `Task` that becomes complete when the `period` elapses. I.e. it is like an asynchronous version of `Thread.Sleep` so execution of the `while` loop resumes after `period` expires.

The end result is that the loop runs forever periodically checking for cancellation (in which case an `OperationCancelledException` is thrown) and executing `func`.

```
public static async Task Periodic(Action func, TimeSpan period, CancellationToken token)
{
    while(true)
    {
        // throws an exception if someone has requested cancellation via the token.
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        func();

        // asynchronously wait 
        await Task.Delay(period);
    }
}
```

In a GUI app you can use it like this:

```
await Periodic(() => /* do something clever here*/, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), CancellationToken.None);
```

The main method of a console app cannot be asynchronous so you cannot use `await` but you can call `Wait()` on the result instead to run it indefinitely and prevent the application from exiting.

```
void Main()
{
    Periodic(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello World!"), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), CancellationToken.None).Wait();
}
```

Care must be taken when calling `Wait()` in a GUI app as it can result in a [deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

**Update**

You may also benefit from having an overload of `Periodic` that takes an `async func`, in case you have an expensive time consuming function you want to run in the background.

```
public async Task Periodic(Func<Task> func, TimeSpan period, CancellationToken token)
{
    while (true)
    {
        // throws an exception if someone has requested cancellation via the token.
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        await func();

        // asynchronously wait 
        await Task.Delay(period);
    }
}
```

Comment: I said that I have a Windows Form Application but   I gave the code for a Console Application. I have changed the code accordingly. Let me try your solution out. I am new to `C#` so I am not very familiar with  `await`.

Comment: I have added my code. The GUI is responsive now. I was constantly moving the form around while testing the code. The form hangs for a couple of seconds and then becomes responsive again. The time interval for which it hangs is not 2 seconds. Sometimes it's around 1 second and sometimes it's around 5 seconds. I do not know why this is happening.

Comment: I added awaits and asyncs to the time consuming function and now the form does not hang. However, there is a delay in displaying the form when I run the application. Is there a good way to remove this? Currently, I am calling the function `hello` in the form's load function.

Comment: You can try running your expensive function in a background thread using `Task.Run` or making the expensive function `async` if possible. A lot of the web retrieval functions have async overloads.